# Finding norm of a linear functional.

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $\{t_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be given points in the closed interval $[0,1]$. Let $\{\omega_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be given real numbers. Let $f\in C[0,1]$. Define
>   $$\varphi(f) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{\omega_if(t_i)}.$$
>   Show that $\varphi$ defines a continuous linear functional on $C[0,1]$ and that
>   $$\|\varphi\| = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{|\omega_i|}.$$

**To show: $||\phi||=\sum_{i=1} ^n|\omega_i|$**

I have done $||\phi||\le\sum_{i=1} ^n|\omega_i|$ by taking **max$f(t_i)$** out of the sum.

How to show $||\phi||\ge\sum_{i=1} ^n|\omega_i|?$

I tried several functions but no one is leading to the result.

Can anyone help me out by figuring out the appropriate $f$?

Comment: Something has been wiped out in your title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, what about a function $f\in C([0,1])$ such that $f(t_i) = \text{sgn}(\omega_i)$ and $|f|\leq1$?

Comment: For example a continuous piece-wise linear  $f$.

Answer (score 2):

If $\mu$ is an atomic measure with atoms at $t_j$ with $\mu\{t_j\}=\omega_j$, then
$$
          \varphi(f) = \int_{0}^{1}f(t)d\mu(t).
$$
It follows from the Riesz representation for $C[0,1]^*$ that
$$
               \|\varphi\| = \|\mu\| = \sum_{j}|\omega_j|. \tag{$*$}
$$
You can prove $(*)$ directly in this case by choosing a function $f$ so that $f(t_j)w_j = |w_j|$ for $1 \le j \le n$, and so that $\|f\|=1$. Then
$$
     \sum_{j}|\omega_j|=\sum_{j}f(t_j)\omega_j=\varphi(f) \le \|\varphi\|\|f\|=\|\varphi\| \\
     \implies \sum_{j}|\omega_j| \le \|\varphi\|.
$$
And, as you noted, for a general $f\in C[0,1]$,
$$
       |\varphi(f)| = |\sum_{j}f(t_j)\omega_j| \le \sum_{j}|f(t_j)||\omega_j| \le \|f\|\sum_{j}|\omega_j| \\
    \implies \|\varphi\| \le \sum_{j}|\omega_j|.
$$
Hence, $\|\varphi\|=\sum_{j}|\omega_j|$.